# How to flash a message in front-end?

Tags: octobercms

How can I flash a message like on this page: https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/flashmessage

What should I include and where?

Exactly I need flash a message after an user submitted some form.
On Octobercms forum I find kind of difficult ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this attribute **data-request-flash** in your form tag like below

```
<form data-request-flash >
```

and add below code on same page/file where your form is

```
{% flash %}
    <p
        data-control="flash-message"
        class="flash-message fade {{ type }}"
        data-interval="5">
        {{ message }}
    </p>
{% endflash %}
```

and suppose your method is like below on component then add flash message like this.

```
<?php 
public function onCustomerRegister(){
    Flash::success("your message is here");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's almost working. The message is showing, but there is no any css and js included for flash. I see only plain text that doesn't disappear. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry, I got it.
It was necessary to add ONLY {% framework extras %}, but I had both {% framework %} and {% framework extras %}. Noob=)

Comment: yep you need to add that  {% framework extras %} for using that css effect of backend. can you upvote the answer please ???

Comment: I upvoted, but because of I have less than 15 rep it won't "change the publicly displayed post score".

Comment: @Евгений what about for the validation (e.g. "The email field is required.")?