# How to show flash message after the registration

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-user-plugin

I am using October cms User plugin.
I have turned on the activation of user. I mean, users need to activate the account after registration.
But after the activation no message displays. I want a flash message to display after successful registration.
Please tell how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-flash

Comment: Hi mike. Thanks for your reply. I found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560181/how-to-flash-a-message-in-front-end